# How to cast from an entity with @Subselect

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have an `@Entity` class A with some `@Columns` and some `@JoinColumns`.

Now I created another `@Entity`class B with the same `@Columns` but no `@JoinColumns` from class A.

And that class B also has `@Immutable` and `@Subselect("select columns from a")`.

Both implements the same interface with the getters and setters, but even that way I get an erro when I try to cast B to A:

```
A a = (A) b
```

is there an easy way to do it, without having to set all the values from one object to the other manually?

Comment: It seems that the problem is that class A extends another class, and class B doesn't extends

Comment: Found this to, maybe, solve the problem: http://modelmapper.org